# '[variable] does not name a type' al utilizar extern

Tags: c++

Según este código que se me dio:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void unaFuncion();
void otraFuncion();
main() {
  extern variable;
  variable = 9;
  printf("El valor de variable es: %d\n", variable);
  unaFuncion();
  printf("Ahora el valor de variable es: %d\n", variable);
  return 0;
}
void unaFuncion() {
  extern variable;
  printf("En la función unaFunción, variable es: %d\n", variable);
}
int variable;
```

Al compilarlo, se muestra el error:

> 'i' does not name a type

Que también causa el error:

> 'i' was not declared in this scope

Intenté mover `unaFuncion` arriba, pero sigue mostrando el error.

Este código viene de un ejercicio de un PDF que me dieron en la escuela.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `otraFuncion`?

Comment: Según el ejemplo del PDF, mostraba un texto con la variable. Al ser dos ejemplos, en este sólo se utiliza para "adornar" el código :s

Comment: Voy a actualizarlo para mostrar mi modificación, sólo puse `otraFuncion` como comentario.

Comment: El compilador se queja que en ningún momento has declarado la variable `i`. Por eso pensé que al final en la función `otraFuncion` estás usando la variable `i` sin haberla declarado..

Comment: Sin entrar en el cuestionable uso de `extern` en ese código, a alguien se le a olvidado el tipo: `extern int variable;` y se paso el tipo del retorno de `main`